# Evaluate Notebook from .Net

Tags: .netlink

How is it possible to send the whole content of an existing notebook to *Mathematica* for evaluation by using NetLink/C#?

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate a notebook from .NET, a batch file and a package file can be used.  This example opens and evaluates a notebook called "run.nb" in the front end.  Ref:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7626491/879601

i.e. batch file:-

```
@echo off
setlocal
PATH = C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\;%PATH%
start MathKernel -noprompt -initfile "C:\Temp\test.m"
endlocal
```

and package file, `"test.m"`:-

```
Needs["JLink`"];
$FrontEndLaunchCommand="Mathematica.exe";
UseFrontEnd[
nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\Temp\\run.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb];
];
Pause[10];
CloseFrontEnd[];
```

The batch file and package file can be created on the fly and run from .NET, (or perhaps you could execute the start command directly and dispense with the batch file).

Alternatively, you could run the main notebook (as a package) in [Mathematica script mode](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html). The above answer uses the front end in order to save output cell information.

Your question mentions evaluating an *existing* notebook, but if you also need to create the notebook in .NET this post may be of use:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321479/879601

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. If I understand you correct, there is now possibilty to use .netLink to evaluate an existing notebook?!? Is ist possible to send parameters to the batch file and also return results? Thank you

Comment: @user6511 - the batch file can be created in .NET on the fly. Retrieval of results from the evaluated notebook depends on the notebook writing data somewhere where it can be read back in by a .NET program.  Otherwise you can get the notebook to save its output using `NotebookSave`.