# running a notebook with a batch file

Tags: windows

I am using Windows (7 if needed). I am trying to learn how to write a batch file that EXECUTES a notebook.

This is the batch

```
@echo off
START "C:\Programmi\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\MathKernel.exe" test.nb
```

it opens mathematica, but doesn't executes the notebook. So I tried (in the notebook) to select the cell and:

```
Cell>Cell properties>Initialization
```

but still it only opens the notebook.

What am I missing?

The notebook:

```
Export["C:\\Users\\MATTIA\\Desktop\\FIT\\Fam_II\\test.jpg", 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

just plots and saves a `sin` function

Comment: Put the commands in a plain text file with extension `.m` and run it [from the command line](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html).

Comment: Try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21832/363 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7428340/879601